# How do I insert anchor tag dynamically in the cell of a table using typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-table, anchor

I am trying to insert a working anchor tag as a link inside the HTML table which I am creating dynamically using typescript, but when I add the anchor tag using innerHTML and append it to the cell, The table only shows the text for anchor tag and the link doesn't work.I am attaching the screenshot of the typescript,html and the frontend.

TypeScript Function

```
populateList(){
let table = document.querySelector("table");
let data=["Sr.No","Exam Name","Link to Exam"];
let thead = table!.createTHead();
let row = table!.insertRow();
  for (const key of data) {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    let text = document.createTextNode(key);
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);
  }

// var tablebody:string=``
// var output:any=[];
// var tablerow:any=[];
// var tableend=``
this.myData.forEach((currentExam:any,examNumber:any) => {
  var htmlVariable=`<a [routerLink]="['session']" [queryParams]="{id:'${currentExam.id}'}">Start Exam</a>`
  let row=table!.insertRow();
  let cell = row!.insertCell();
  let text = document.createTextNode(`${examNumber}`)
  cell.appendChild(text);
  cell=row.insertCell();
  text=document.createTextNode(`${currentExam.examName}`);
  cell.appendChild(text);
  cell=row.insertCell();
  var content=document.createElement("div");
  content.innerHTML=htmlVariable;
  cell.appendChild(content);
});
```

HTML Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Welcome to Student Homepage.</h1>
    <table class="center">
    </table>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

FrontEnd Screenshot.

[image]

How can I add a working anchor tag dynamically to the cell element of an HTML table using typescript?

Comment: Please add your code as text, images make it harder to find this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are creating the html in javascript instead of using the angular template engine?

Comment: Are you sure you are using AngularJS instead of angular?

Comment: I am using Angular

Comment: If you could suggest me an alternate way of doing the same thing, that would be helpful,I am new to Angular

Comment: I have changed the tag from AngularJS to Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following setup to dynamically build a table:

> students.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-students",
  templateUrl: "./students.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./students.component.css"]
})
export class StudentsComponent {
  tableColumnLabels = ["Sr.No", "Exam Name", "Link to Exam"];

  exams = [
    { id: "1", name: "first Exam" },
    { id: "2", name: "second Exam" }
  ];
}
```

> students.component.html

```html
<table>
  <th *ngFor="let columnLabel of tableColumnLabels">{{ columnLabel }}</th>
  <tr *ngFor="let exam of exams; index as examNumber;">
    <td>{{ examNumber }}</td>
    <td>{{ exam.name }}</td>
    <td>
      <a [routerLink]="['session']" [queryParams]="{id: exam.id}">Start Exam</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can easily add more components using `ng generate component MyComponent`.

Comment: Thank you very much,This solved my issue.